# Simple elasticsearch input - Rejecting mapping update final mapping would have more than 1 type: [_doc, doc]

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to send data to elasticsearch but running into an issue where my number field only comes up as a string. These are the steps I took.

Step 1. Add index & map

```
PUT http://123.com:5101/core_060619/

{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "date": {
        "type":   "date",
        "format": "HH:mm yyyy-MM-dd"
      },
        "data": {
        "type":   "integer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
{
    "acknowledged": true,
    "shards_acknowledged": true,
    "index": "core_060619"
}
```

Step 2. Add data

```
PUT http://123.com:5101/core_060619/doc/1

{
  "test" : [ {
    "data" : "119050300",
    "date" : "00:00 2019-06-03"
  } ]
}
```

Result:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                "reason": "Rejecting mapping update to [zyxnewcoreyxbl_060619] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [_doc, doc]"
            }
        ],
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Rejecting mapping update to [zyxnewcoreyxbl_060619] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [_doc, doc]"
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

Comment: can you post results from `GET http://123.com:5101/core_060619/_mapping`?

Comment: @DejanMarić yes its ```{
    "core_060619": {
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "data": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "date": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "HH:mm yyyy-MM-dd"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can not have more than **one** type of document in `Elasticsearch 6.0.0+`. If you set your document type to `doc`, then you can add another document by simply `PUT http://123.com:5101/core_060619/doc/1`, `PUT http://123.com:5101/core_060619/doc/2` etc.

**Elasticsearch 6.+**

```
PUT core_060619/
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {     //type of documents in index is 'doc'
     "properties": {
        "date": {
          "type":   "date",
          "format": "HH:mm yyyy-MM-dd"
        },
          "data": {
          "type":   "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Since we created mapping to have `doc` type of documents, now we can add new documents by simply adding `/doc/_id`:

```
PUT core_060619/doc/1
{
  "test" : [ {
    "data" : "119050300",
    "date" : "00:00 2019-06-03"
  } ]
}


PUT core_060619/doc/2
{
  "test" : [ {
    "data" : "111120300",
    "date" : "10:15 2019-06-02"
  } ]
}
```

**Elasticsearch 7.+**

Types are removed, but you can use custom like field(s):

```
PUT twitter
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "type": { "type": "keyword" }, 
        "name": { "type": "text" },
        "user_name": { "type": "keyword" },
        "email": { "type": "keyword" },
        "content": { "type": "text" },
        "tweeted_at": { "type": "date" }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT twitter/_doc/user-kimchy
{
  "type": "user", 
  "name": "Shay Banon",
  "user_name": "kimchy",
  "email": "shay@kimchy.com"
}

PUT twitter/_doc/tweet-1
{
  "type": "tweet", 
  "user_name": "kimchy",
  "tweeted_at": "2017-10-24T09:00:00Z",
  "content": "Types are going away"
}

GET twitter/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "user_name": "kimchy"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "match": {
          "type": "tweet" 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Removal of mapping types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.1/removal-of-types.html)

Comment: Thank you Dejan. When I do ```{
  "mappings": {
    "user": {
      "properties": {
        "data": { "type": "integer" },
        "date": { "type": "date" }
      }
    }
  }
}``` I get Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters

Comment: which version of ES are you using?

Comment: the code for 7.x is the example of the old way to do the thing as explained in Removal of mapping types:
Let’s take the user/tweet example above. Originally, the workflow would have looked something like this:

Comment: this doesnt work on 7.13.2
`The mapping definition cannot be nested under a type [_doc] unless include_type_name is set to true.`